# Infiltrator Ranger without Favored Enemy

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Would it be possible have a Ranger with the [Infiltrator](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/ranger/archetypes/paizo---ranger-archetypes/infiltrator) archetype with another archetype such as [Guide](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/ranger/archetypes/paizo---ranger-archetypes/guide) or [Wild Hunter](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/ranger/archetypes/paizo---ranger-archetypes/wild-hunter) that replaces the Favored Enemy class feature? If so how would it work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Technically,* you could choose the Infiltrator archetype if you didn't have Favored Enemy - its prerequisite is the Favored Terrain class feature. *But,* you wouldn't get any benefit from it (and would lose Favored Terrain).

> At 3rd level, an infiltrator learns how to copy the unusual abilities of his prey. He chooses one type of creature he has selected as a favored enemy, such as “aberrations.” The Ranger selects one ability or feat from the adaptation list for that type (see below). A Ranger can use adaptations for 10 minutes per day per Ranger level he possesses. This duration does not need to be consecutive, but it must be used in 10-minute increments.

Step 1: *Choose one type of creature you have selected as a favored enemy*.

"So, I can choose any one of my **zero** favored enemies... why did I choose this archetype?"

Answer (score 1):

I had a PFS GM handwave it. As long as I took Infiltrator first and then Wild Hunter he would let me still use adaptations but I wouldn't get favored enemy bonuses and such. Seemed fair to me.